# How to add schema in a Wordpress site for Google knowledge graph?

Tags: wordpress, schema, wikipedia, knowledge-management

I'm confused to add schema in my Wordpress site for Google knowledge graph. I would like to show my knowledge graph in Google like - Royal Caribbean and ASOS etc. I'm not a brand like that as well as don't have Wikipedia Page too. But, I would like to add this information - my company name, founder, founded year, content, social media links etc. 
Someone suggest me for this.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to add microdata to your WordPress site is using a plugin, you can find some interesting plugins for this purpose here:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/microdata

Another option to add structured data markup is adding the snippets "by hand" on a contact page or in a text widget.

For more information have a look at *schema.org/docs/gs.html* and at *developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/overview*.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the de facto standard concept schema:LocalBusiness and its properties from http://schema.org/LocalBusiness. On the bottom of this page, there are examples for implementing organizational data as structured data in serializations such as HTML5 Microdata, RDFa, and JSON-LD.

Once you implemented the code, you can test it at https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool to make sure that it contains no errors and it is ready to be indexed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Install it in the usual way by going to Plugins > Add New and searching for Schema. Click Install and then Activate. Once the plugin is installed and activated, go to Schema > Settings to start adding Schema markup to your site.
You can validate your schema markups by Google's Structured Data Markup Validation Tool.